# Не работает блокировка для большого количества запросов

Tags: javascript, mysql, алгоритм, node.js

Здравствуйте. Дело в том, что я использую сокеты. И почти в одно и то же время, допустим, в 20 часов и 0 минут, у всех пользователей скрипт отправляет запрос на сокет сервер. Отправляя этот запрос, у меня есть цель: выполнить нужное мне событие (1.1) один раз, и вернуть всем результаты. Но у меня не совсем получается.

Я делаю так: когда приходит запрос от пользователя я проверяю, был ли запрос раньше, и если не было, помечаю в базе, что запрос только что произошел. Дальше, если еще кто-то шлет запрос, то уже видно, что запрос уже произошел, и текущий клиент ждет выполнения нужного мне события (1.1). Проблема состоит в том, что иногда Node.JS не успевает выполнить запрос к базе, и за это время, пока идёт запрос, успевает "проскочить" несколько клиентов и нужно мне события (1.1) выполняется столько раз, сколько пользователей проскочило, плюс тот пользователь, что инициировал первый запрос.

Как быть? Может есть какой-то алгоритм? Уже голову сломал.

Comment: можете выполнить `select status from ... for update` при этом запись заблокируется до завершения транзакции. Все остальные будут ждать блокировку и когда блок завершится, они уже увидят обновленный статус

Comment: @Mike а есть статейка на эту тему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно использовать именнованые локи MySQL

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('lock_name', 60);
```

[Документация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)

Comment: а в чем минус этой конструкции?

Comment: небольшой минус - можно использовать только в рамках одного mysql сервера. а так в принципе для решения поставленной задачи должно подойти